# Print command output

Tags: java, c, floating-point

Here is a code snippet of for a C program.,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    float kk=2*3/4+4/4+8-2;
    printf("%f",kk);
}
```

The output of this program is 8.000000

The same code written in JAVA 8.

```
class Untitled {
public static void main(String[] args) {
float kk=2*3/4+4/4+8-2;
System.out.println("\n----- Converting to the precision -----\n");
System.out.printf("%f",kk);
System.out.println("\n----- Converting to the Integer -----\n");
System.out.println(kk);
    }
}
```

Output of this program is 8.0 with the println method. The printf method was returning the value with proper precision. From printstream documentation, I was not understanding how the complier was loosing the precision. I was hoping there will some warning or something where the lost precision would be notified., any thoughts of how to identify these type of gotchas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: because Java is not C, look up [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) in the JavaDocs. This is not about `precision` it is about the output format.

Comment: You're not losing precision.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, JAVA is not C. But I want to know why am I loosing the precision that I get i C.

Comment: You are NOT losing precision. The output format is simply different. Try using `printf("%3.10f", kk)`, and you will have more digits printed out, and the value will be the same mathematically.

Comment: `8.00000` and `8.0` is the same number. As @iamnotmaynard says, this is not "losing precision". Try printing the square-root of 2 and compare the C output with the Java output, **that** is what precision is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consult the documentation for `printf` in C and `System.out.println` in Java, you will see that they format output in different ways. This is because they are totally different, and I'm not sure why you expected them to produce the same results.

If you want printf-style formatting in Java, consider using `String.format()` to format the output, or using `System.out.printf()`, which still may require explicit formatting widths to be identical to the default behavior of `printf` in C ([which is 6 decimal places if not explicitly specified](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), hence your `8.000000`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in Java also.  Replace

```
System.out.println(kk);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("%f", kk);
```

You're not losing precision with Java; it's just that there are differing output formats.

Answer (score 1):

In both java and C the code `float kk=2*3/4+4/4+8-2;` will treat the right-hand side as integers.... since there is no reason to implicity cast them to anything else.

As a result, the answer will always be an integer value (integer division, e.g. `2*3/4` will give the result `1` even though in floating point it is 1.5).

Thus, there is not any floating-point precision anyway, so nothing to lose.

Comment: Even if the calculations had been made floating point, every value involved, including all intermediate results, would be an exact binary fraction of moderate size, and so exactly representable.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually losing that much precision. You may be losing a bit (I won't go into depth on the petty details), but the reason you only get 8.0 is simply a difference in the print command. JAVA's rounds off whereas C's does not round so quickly.

Try printing something that is not an integer in floating-point form (i.e. divide your answer by, say, 11) and it should show the extra digits as needed.

Comment: While there may be rounding that is not the true reason for the `8.000000` output in C. The real reason is in C, `%f` defaults to 6 digits after the decimal if precision is not explicitly specified. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/.